# Android Webview function calls not always working

Tags: android, webview

I want to be able to zoom by webview to a given zoomfactor, and scroll to a specific coordinate.

Since we're targeting API 19 we can't use zoomBy() (which was introduced in APi 21) and insted have to try to approximate the zoom.

Which is already done and working. At least in theory.

Here's the code:

```
private void zoomWebview(int x, int y, int width, int height){
    int webviewWidth = mainWebview.getWidth();
    int webviewHeight = mainWebview.getHeight();

    float scaleX = (float)webviewWidth / width;
    float scaleY = (float)webviewHeight / height;

    final float scale;

    System.out.println("Scale X: "+scaleX);
    System.out.println("Scale Y: "+scaleY);

    if(scaleX < scaleY){
        scale = scaleX;
    }else{
        scale = scaleY;
    }

    System.out.println("Needed scale: "+scale);

    final int transX = x;
    final int transY = y;

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            float prevZoomFactor = mainWebview.getScale();

            if(mainWebview.getScale() > scale){
                do{
                    mainWebview.zoomOut();
                    System.out.println("Zoom out from "+prevZoomFactor+" to "+mainWebview.getScale());
                    if(prevZoomFactor == mainWebview.getScale()){
                        //In case zoomOut() wasn't able to actually zoom, break to prevent infinite loop
                        break;
                    }

                    prevZoomFactor = mainWebview.getScale();
                }while(mainWebview.getScale() > scale);
            }else{
                do{
                    mainWebview.zoomIn();
                    System.out.println("Zoom in from "+prevZoomFactor+" "+mainWebview.getScale());
                    if(prevZoomFactor == mainWebview.getScale()){
                        //In case zoomIn() wasn't able to actually zoom, break to prevent infinite loop
                        break;
                    }

                    prevZoomFactor = mainWebview.getScale();
                }while(mainWebview.getScale() < scale);

                //Make sure we do not cut off any content. Rather show a little border
                mainWebview.zoomOut();
            }
            System.out.println("Final zoom: "+mainWebview.getScale());

            mainWebview.scrollTo(Math.round(transX*mainWebview.getScale()), Math.round(transY*mainWebview.getScale()));
            System.out.println("Scroll to "+Math.round(transX*mainWebview.getScale())+"|"+Math.round(transY*mainWebview.getScale()));
        }
    });
}
```

Most interesting part is the part which is supposed to run on the main thread. Sometimes the webview functions are working, and sometimes not.

I can call this function with a buttonclick. I pushed the button 4 times in a row. The first 3 times nothing happend, but on the 4th tr it suddenly works.

And this is reproducable, not always after a certain amount of clicks, but it will certainly work at some point.

Here's the console output:

```
07-23 08:09:46.304: I/System.out(25659): Scale X: 1.8285714
07-23 08:09:46.304: I/System.out(25659): Scale Y: 2.371191
07-23 08:09:46.304: I/System.out(25659): Needed scale: 1.8285714
07-23 08:09:46.304: I/System.out(25659): Zoom in from 1.6790987 1.6790987
07-23 08:09:46.304: I/System.out(25659): Final zoom: 1.6790987
07-23 08:09:46.305: I/System.out(25659): Scroll to 49|12
07-23 08:09:47.117: I/System.out(25659): Scale X: 1.8285714
07-23 08:09:47.117: I/System.out(25659): Scale Y: 2.371191
07-23 08:09:47.117: I/System.out(25659): Needed scale: 1.8285714
07-23 08:09:47.120: I/System.out(25659): Zoom in from 1.6790987 1.6790987
07-23 08:09:47.121: I/System.out(25659): Final zoom: 1.6790987
07-23 08:09:47.121: I/System.out(25659): Scroll to 49|12
07-23 08:09:47.749: I/System.out(25659): Scale X: 1.8285714
07-23 08:09:47.749: I/System.out(25659): Scale Y: 2.371191
07-23 08:09:47.749: I/System.out(25659): Needed scale: 1.8285714
07-23 08:09:47.751: I/System.out(25659): Zoom in from 1.6790987 1.6790987
07-23 08:09:47.751: I/System.out(25659): Final zoom: 1.6790987
07-23 08:09:47.752: I/System.out(25659): Scroll to 49|12
07-23 08:09:48.298: I/System.out(25659): Scale X: 1.8285714
07-23 08:09:48.298: I/System.out(25659): Scale Y: 2.371191
07-23 08:09:48.298: I/System.out(25659): Needed scale: 1.8285714
07-23 08:09:48.314: I/System.out(25659): Zoom in from 1.6790987 2.0988734
07-23 08:09:48.314: I/System.out(25659): Final zoom: 1.6790987
07-23 08:09:48.314: I/System.out(25659): Scroll to 49|12
```

The last 6 entries describe the event where it suddenly worked. Notice how the webview was suddenly able to zoom from 1.67 to 2.09. And also the scrollTo function, although called with the same values.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the (already deprecated) call of `mainWebview.getScale()`.

The solution was to use a custom `WebViewController` in which I implemented an `onScaleChanged-Listener` to get the current scale of my webview.

To synchronize my Zoom-Function with my listener I used a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: Can you post some example code? For me I'm finding that `onScaleChanged` never gets called, even after calling `webView.zoomBy`. It might be a synchronization issue, but I tried waiting for 5 seconds and the listener was still not called.